# resource dictionary with escape characters doesn't resolve the the escaped character

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using multiple xaml file as a resource dictionary, the problem is that when the text are shown the escaped character aren't translated back.
For example this is the code

```
<clr:String x:Key = "CMMsg_143">Cannot rename file &amp;quot;%s&amp;quot; to &amp;quot;%s&amp;quot; - %s</clr:String>
```

instead of showing Cannot rename file "%s" to "%s" - %s it write Cannot rename file &quot;%s&quot; to &quot;%s&quot; - %s

this is how I add it

```
using (System.IO.FileStream stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(file))
            {
                System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader reader = new System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader();
                ResourceDictionary myResourceDictionary = (ResourceDictionary)reader.LoadAsync(stream);
                this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
            }
```

The usage would be something like this.

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource DefBtn}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="button_CreateElement" Content="{DynamicResource CMMsg_143}" Click="button_CreateElement_Click"/>
```

or from code behind.

```
(String)this.FindResource("CMMsg_143");
```

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: You need to show us your code.

Comment: @Enigmativity any ideas?

Comment: What's the encoding of your file?

Comment: @VegaBrothers - You might need to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simpy define the `string` like this in your `ResourceDictionary`?

```
<clr:String x:Key="CMMsg_143">Cannot rename file "%s" to "%s" - %s</clr:String>
```

There is no reason to try to escape the quotes in a `string` that you define in XAML.

Comment: That would be invalid XML.

Comment: No. It works wonders for me. You are obviously doing something strange with your ResourceDictionary. And your question doesn't make much sense. Why would &amp;quot be printed out as "?

Comment: The only thing that is invalid here since to be the value of your string. So change it to a valid value and you are all set.

Comment: Are not `"` required to be `&quot;`? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML

Comment: Ah, I just read the spec `"To allow attribute values to contain both single and double quotes, the apostrophe or single-quote character (') may be represented as " &apos; ", and the double-quote character (") as " &quot; "."`. If you can do a minor edit to your answer I can then remove the downvote.

Comment: A *string* defined in XAML can contain unescaped quotes. You don't set any attribute of a System.String.

Comment: If you can do a minor edit to your answer I can then remove the down-vote. Right now it's locked and I can't.